# Spring web flow not being followed between pages on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, spring-webflow

I have a two page flow made with spring web flow (version 1.0.5). It works ok in Firefox, but in Chrome I can't go to the second page, as

```
org.springframework.webflow.executor.support.RequestParameterFlowExecutorArgumentHandler.isFlowExecutionKeyPresent()
```

return false. I guess that key is being saved in a httpsession. I tried deleting all cookies and history from the browsers with no avail. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: can't see where the anti-java folks get that java is verbose... the method is only 116 characters ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there is a problem with the hidden field used in the JSP page to keep track of the flow

```
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
```

Check the source page in Chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but it started working again. My view is in freemarker, but anyway I thought that key was held in the session, so there was no need to pass it through post/get parameters.